# onTouch method with ViewHolder Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have a BaseAdapter that implements OnTouchListener class. The onTouch method is:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        startY = event.getY();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float endY = event.getY();

        if (endY > startY) {
            layoutComments.startAnimation(animDown);
            layoutComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem in that the layoutComments variable is inserted in a ViewHolder declarated in a getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
...
...
```

The program can't view the variable, and there are two compiler errors. How can I get the ViewHolder from the variable v of the onTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the general design practice to set the ViewHolder as the tag on the view, `convertView.setTag(holder)`, so it can be retrieved whenever you have a reference to the view via: `(ViewHolder) view.getTag()`

Comment: actually, I see that the BaseAdapter don't see the event. Any ideas?